# Functional way of handling configuration for a library

Tags: f#, functional-programming

In C# a library might expose an interface which implementation you provide using a DI container, what is the functional way to go about this? I want to make something configurable in a library ('library-wide') and be able to set in from the main code.

Comment: Generally it turns out in practice that there are only one-two functions in a library that _actually_ need the configuration. So the usual practice is to just pass the configuration as a parameter. If you are really sure that your library has many functions that require a configuration, you may consider implementing it as an interface. In any case, you need to be clearer on what you actually want to do. In C# dependency injection is a default go-to practice, but in functional programming it's not, so you have to actually think about whether you want to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly still use an interface and a DI container in F#.  However, there are other approaches that functional programming offers that may also work for you.  Some options might be:

**Partial Application**:  You have a set of functions in a module that take the configuration information as their first parameter (say, as a record type).  You can then partially apply these functions, passing just the configuration, returning functions that just take the remaining parameters.  For example:

```
type Config =
    {
        ConnectionString: string
        SuperMode: bool
        NumberOfWidgets: int
    }

module Library =
    let login (config: Config) userName passwordHash =
        // do stuff
        ()

    let createWidget (config: Config) widgetName widgetValue =
        // do stuff
        ()

let config = {ConnectionString = "localhost"; SuperMode = true; NumberOfWidgets = 3}

let configuredLogin = Library.login config // configuredLogin is a function taking userName and passwordHash
let configuredCreateWidget = Library.createWidget config // configuredCreateWidget is a function taking widgetName and widgetValu
```

**Closures**:  You have a function that accepts the configuration and returns one or more other functions that close over the configuration and use it when called.  For example:

```
let applyConfig (config: Config) =
    (fun userName passwordHash -> 
        Library.login config userName passwordHash), // do login using the config
    (fun widgetName widgetValue ->
        Library.createWidget config widgetName widgetValue) // create the widget using the config

let login, createWidget = applyConfig config // Returns functions that close over the Config and use it when called
```

Choose whichever way best suits your needs, and don't rule out using a proven approach you're familiar with just because it isn't 'functional'.